# The argument type 'ServiceDataProvider can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ServiceDataProvider Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webapi

i have this kind of prob, i want integrate Flutter with .Net core web API. I'm new to flutter so, i just followed the tutorial, i put servicedataprovider in its place and somehow, it's got error.

```
ServiceDataProvider serviceDataProvider= ServiceDataProvider(httpClient: http.Client(),);
  final ServiceRepository serviceRepository = ServiceRepository(
    dataProvider:serviceDataProvider
  );
```

the error message doestn help to solve this problem. how to solve this

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the right ServiceDataProvider?